# Connect to Azure Blob from Local environment

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

Problem:
I am following an Azure Quickstart [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) to the letter. I have created the Azure accounts and the Storage Accounts.

When trying to do the simple quickstart, I'm getting errors on the first call the the Azure cloud. This call

> Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(String
>   blobContainerName, PublicAccessType publicAccessType, IDictionary`2
>   metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

is throwing this exception:

> (No such host is known.)  ---> Azure.RequestFailedException: No such
>   host is known.

The code couldn't be simpler so I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to run local code against an Azure Blob database?
2. If yes, what might be wrong in the configuration, the version or some quirk?

Code:

```
        string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

        string containerName = "quickstartblobs" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        //Error occurs here.
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName);
```

Assuming I set the environment variable and used the connection keys exactly right, what could be causing this error?

This is the client library I'm using on DotNetCore 3.1:
Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.4.2"

Here are the settings for my Azure account's Blob Storage app.
[image: Azure Blob Storage Settings]

I am a newbie to Cloud Computing, so please be gentle.

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=gordonsfirstblob;AccountKey=(key from Azure)+HYCDJYzQkw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

Thanks!

Comment: Your connection string looks ok to me. Please check the account name. Also check if there is a proxy server in between that might be blocking your request. This error comes when the account endpoint (gordonsfirstblob.blob.core.windows.net) is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to run local code against an Azure Blob database?

Yes, off course.

I can reproduce your error. Problem should comes from your connection string of storage account.

I can download data from azure storage account to local:

```
string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxEndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
BlobServiceClient myClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
var container = myClient.GetBlobContainerClient("video");
var blockBlob = container.GetBlobClient("test.txt");
blockBlob.DownloadTo("C:\\Users\\bowmanzh\\Desktop\\123.txt");
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

Please copy connection string from this place, make sure the account name and others is no problem:

[image]

If still not, you can try to use another machine. Your code seems no problem.